# Java regex pattern between two character having repetitive appearance

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a text file containing string

```
<><> name: idontknow <><><> dob: <>
```

I want to get only the strings name and dob but with the regex i am getting <> name and <><> dob.
The regex pattern which i used is

```
(?<=>).*?(?=:)
```

Any suggestion would be a great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to match characters apart from `<` or `>`. You can use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) instead of using `.` which matches anything:

```
[^<>]*?(?=:)
```

See it working online: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/11Z1trB1JI)

Comment: Add `\b` to the beginning to avoid matching the leading space

Comment: @user1727977 - If this answer was right, please add the green check next to it.